# How do I have an object face the mouse in p5?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm have a problem making an object face the mouse and the websites tutorials don't help!

```
function draw() {
    background(0, backgroundColor2, 0); 
    cursor('crosshair.png')
    frameRate(1000);
    angleMode(DEGREES);  
    imageMode(CORNER)
    let a = atan2(mouseY - height / 2, mouseX - width / 2);
    rotate(a);
    image(gun, width/2, height/2, 40, 40);
}
```

Comment: I'm rotating an image

Comment: Having an object rotate with the angle corresponding with the position of the mouse

Comment: please describe what you are seeing and what you expect to see

Comment: Heres what Im seeing (please ignore the courser) : https://editor.p5js.org/TheDiamondfinderYT/present/C76AXappV

Comment: What I want to see is the pitchfork stay in the middle and point towards the mouse

Comment: Try translating to the middle of the canvas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object is rotating but it is rotating on 0, 0

So if you want the object to rotate on the center of the screen then,

```
    function draw() {
       background(0, backgroundColor2, 0); 
       cursor('crosshair.png')
       frameRate(1000);
       angleMode(DEGREES);  
       imageMode(CORNER)
       let a = atan2(mouseY - height / 2, mouseX - width / 2);
       translate(width/2, height/2);
       rotate(a);
       image(gun, 0, 0, 40, 40);
    }
```

Here is a link for you to understand better
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9sgjuh-CBM